# Layout in social network analysis. library(igraph)

Tags: r, igraph

I built a social network:

[image]

My code:

```
plot(network, edge.width=E(network)$importance, layout=layout.sphere, vertex.color = "red", edge.color = "red", vertex.frame.color = "red", vertex.size = as.numeric(V(network)$vertex.size), vertex.label.cex=as.numeric(V(network)$vertex.label.cex))
```

I have a question, how to bring the location of the points, as in the photo:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "bring the location of the points"?

Comment: In the photo from the example, the points are located at the same distance from each other. And I get something strange, because the points are located anywhere.

Comment: Without your data, it is very hard to recommend a better layout.  Please type `dput(network)` and paste the results into your question so that we can help you.